# Get selected from Listbox tkinter

Tags: tkinter, listbox, selection

I have created a Listbox that appear when a button is clicked.

```
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as tk


window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("100x100")

def test_listbox():
    list = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
    listbox_selectcolumns = Listbox(window, selectmode='multiple', width=30, height=10)
    listbox_selectcolumns.place(anchor='nw')

    for col in range(len(list)):
        listbox_selectcolumns.insert(END, list[col])

listbox_selectcolumns = Listbox(window)
Btm = Button(window, text = "Run listbox", command=test_listbox)
Btm.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

How do I get the selected items from the Listbox?

I have tried to use bind that call another function which was suppose to print the selected value.

```
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("100x100")

def test_listbox():
    list = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']

    listbox_selectcolumns = Listbox(window, selectmode='multiple', width=30, height=10)
    listbox_selectcolumns.place(anchor='nw')

    for col in range(len(list)):
        listbox_selectcolumns.insert(END, list[col])

    listbox_selectcolumns.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", listbox_selection)

def listbox_selection(self):
    for i in listbox_selectcolumns.curselection():
        print(i)

listbox_selectcolumns = Listbox(window)
Btm = Button(window, text = "Run listbox", command=test_listbox)
Btm.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the `listbox_selectcolumns` inside `listbox_selection()` is the one created in the global scope, not the one created inside `test_listbox()`.

You should not create the global instance.  Also you can create a global list to store the selected items.

```py
import tkinter as tk

selected_items = []  # list to store the selected items

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("100x100")

def test_listbox():
    list = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']

    listbox_selectcolumns = tk.Listbox(window, selectmode='multiple', width=30, height=10)
    listbox_selectcolumns.place(anchor='nw')

    for col in range(len(list)):
        listbox_selectcolumns.insert(tk.END, list[col])

    listbox_selectcolumns.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", listbox_selection)

def listbox_selection(event):
    listbox = event.widget
    # clear the list
    selected_items.clear() 
    # append the selected items to the list
    selected_items.extend(listbox.get(i) for i in listbox.curselection())
    print(selected_items)

Btm = tk.Button(window, text = "Run listbox", command=test_listbox)
Btm.pack()

window.mainloop()
```